# Updating queries with Slick 3.0.2/Scala

Tags: scala, slick

Need to update table in slick 3.0.2 while using scala/playframework.

```
      form.fold (
          errForm => {
            BadRequest();
          },
          data => {
           ** update each column of the table after running db.run 
          }
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose your form object has 3 fields a, b, and c. then your update statement will look like

```
val query = db_user_info.filter(_.username === data.username).map(r => (r.a, r.b, r.c)).update(form.a, form.b, form.c)
```